# How to hide or remove search bar in UiWebView in iPhone

Tags: iphone, iphone-standalone-web-app

I am using web view in my app but i don't want the search bar at the top i want it to hide or remove from webview so can any one give me the solution for it.

Answer (score 0):

Your question needs a bit of clarification.  Is this a web app running in Safari on iPhone?  A UIWebview doesn't have a search bar, so I'm assuming this is a web app, in which case add this meta tag to the web content:-

```
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
```

...but this only works if when the user adds the page to their 'home view' (Springboard).  For more information, see:-

http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/appleapplications/reference/SafariHTMLRef/Articles/MetaTags.html